# C++ console not showing menu

Tags: c++

If the user selects 1 or 2, function doesn't run. Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void getTitle();
void getIsbn();

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;      // Stores user's menu choice

    do
    {
        // Display menu
        cout << "             Main Menu\n\n\n";

        // Display menu items
        cout << "   1. Choose 1 to enter Title.\n";
        cout << "   2. Choose 2 to enter ISBN.\n";
        cout << "   3. Choose 3 to exit.\n";

        // Display prompt and get user's choice
        cout << "   Enter your choice: ";
        cin  >> choice;

        // Validate user's entry
        while (choice < 1 || choice > 3)
        {
            cout << "\n   Please enter a number in the range 1 - 3. ";
            cin  >> choice;
        }

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            getTitle();
            break;
        case 2:
            getIsbn();
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 3);

    return 0;
}

void getTitle()
{
    string title;
    cout << "\nEnter a title: ";
    getline(cin, title);
    cout << "\nTitle is " << title << "\n\n\n";
}

void getIsbn()
{
    string isbn;
    cout << "\nEnter an ISBN: ";
    getline(cin, isbn);
    cout << "\nISBN is " << isbn << "\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Mhhh, are you sure that cin reads the int as an int?because if it reads it as a string, maybe the "number" inside choice is something out of range. Another thing, when you put 1 or 2, did you notice if the program goes outside the inner while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions should certainly get called. What will happen, though, is that the newline generated when you press "Enter" to type the number will get returned by the `getline()`, and the function will return without really prompting you. You need to clear that newline. You can use `ignore()` to do this: add `cin.ignore();` immediately after reading in `choice` to ignore the one character.